# How to get "out" of the full screen in applications on iPhone?

Tags: applications, ios

I'm often using some news applications (like WP.PL) which sometimes enter in full screen mode on my iPhone. It means all the buttons dissapear and there's only text/photos to read. Swiping left/right switches between news but all I would like to do is to get out of the full screen and continue reading with ability to change categories etc.
I tried multiple options and 99% of times it gets out of full screen mode but it's more of a random pushing the glass (multiple times) than actually "knowing" how to leave full screen.

Is there some sort of finger combination for all applications or is per app setting I have to leave with ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a per app setting. but most app follow the standard settings.

try tapping once in the middle on the screen and see if the controls now show up.

Comment: Seems to work fine. Must be that i pressed too many times and it was turning itself off and on right away.